# Extracting a substring in SAS using regex

Tags: regex, string, sas, substring

**Problem**

I need to extract a specific string from HTML using regex. The name of the string always follows the following pattern:

`<2 digits><any number of characters>.zip`

I would like to do this in one step.

**What I have**

```
data have;
    infile datalines truncover;
    input Line $ 1-500;
    datalines;
"<td><a href=""Location/01data.zip"">2001</td>"
"<td><a href=""Location/02moarstuff.zip"">2002</td>"
;
run;
```

**What I need**

The file's name and extension from the HTML code.

```
File               Line                                                   
01data.zip         "<td><a href=""Location/01data.zip"">2001</td>"         
02moarstuff.zip    "<td><a href=""Location/02moarstuff.zip"">2002</td>"
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried using the following regular expression:

`/\d+\w+(\.zip)/`

After testing with http://regexr.com/ , the expression does find the right string. I then tried to use a technique found on [page 3 of this SAS regex whitepaper](http://www.pharmasug.org/proceedings/2013/CC/PharmaSUG-2013-CC35.pdf) to remove everything except for the desired substring by using the `prxchange()` function:

```
data want;
    length File $25.;
    set have;

    file=prxchange('s/^.*\d+\w+(\.zip).*$/$1/',-1, line);
run;
```

This will get me:

```
File    Line                                                   
.zip    "<td><a href=""Location/01data.zip"">2001</td>"         
.zip    "<td><a href=""Location/02moarstuff.zip"">2002</td>"
```

It ends up replacing the string with `.zip`, but I am missing the file's name. I've tried different values of `$` in the replacement, but no success.

**Question**

What am I doing wrong with this regex replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly there. Just grouping over the wrong objects:

```
file=prxchange('s/^.*\d{2}(\w+\.zip).*$/$1/',-1, line);
```